# Is there a list of AJAX JSF Libraries available?

Tags: ajax, jsf, user-interface, components, package

I'm looking for an alternative to [www.jsfmatrix.net](http://www.jsfmatrix.net/) to get a better idea of what JSF libraries are out there and to avoid having to write my own grid/table components. Or are these 27 the best the world has to offer (really only 3 are worth their salt.)

Answer (score 2):

have you looked at RichFaces? It comes with a lot really cool rich UI stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second RichFaces, but also point out IceFaces (which isn't free, but is also very nice).